# filter products by age in magento site

Tags: theme, filter, filtered-nav

We are devoloping a "toys for kids" magento site.

So we are planning for main categories = Boys & girls.

along with that we have to filter products as "0-2 years" , "2-4" years, "4-6years"..etc.

I guess it's similar like "shop by price[0-100] , [100-200] & shop by color".

you can see demo here, below gallery images  : http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/46006.html

please guide me to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello It's very easy in Magento.

**Step 1:** First you have to create Attribute for example `age`. Make this attribute as Drop Down.

**Step 2:** Make Setting as below Image.

[image]

**Step 3:** Assign the values in second tab and Save attribute.

> 0-2 years
>
> 2-4 years
>
> 4-6 years

**Step 4:** Assign this `attribute` to `attribute set`.

**Step 5:** Now Open any product which has assign `attribute set`.

**Step 6:** Assign that value at product level and save configuration.

**Step 7:** Re-index Magento Data and Refresh Cache.

**Step 8:** Now Open that category listing that product attributes will display in `layered Navigation`.

Comment: yes Sure It's default Magento functionality it will working

Comment: you are welcome. :)